# How to get Proper Out for df -k command

Tags: disk-usage

I am facing one issue when using df -k command. I need the result to be in proper format so that I can use it for another purpose.

System 1 - I have used this command ( df -k | tr -s " "  )

Output 1

```
$ df -k | tr -s " "
Filesystem 1024-blocks Free %Used Iused %Iused Mounted on
/dev/hd4 1703936 1317848 23% 7154 1% /
/dev/hd2 4849664 2106456 57% 57120 5% /usr
/dev/hd9var 3670016 939564 75% 16242 2% /var
/dev/hd3 3932160 3787604 4% 382 1% /tmp
/dev/hd1 5242880 1046220 81% 71598 6% /home
/proc - - - - - /proc
/dev/hd10opt 2228224 440928 81% 17096 4% /opt
/dev/ecclv 1048576 165284 85% 2928 2% /opt/ecc
/dev/metriclv 131072 96768 27% 102 1% /var/adm/metric
/dev/perflv 262144 120840 54% 80 1% /var/opt/perf
/dev/carhome_lv 10485760 7249912 31% 264574 15% /xcarapps/prod
/dev/cdnhome_lv 59572224 11050440 82% 2317 1% /apps5
/dev/ccds_lv 27230208 21092196 23% 1075858 19% /apps2
/dev/appslv 2293760 1848688 20% 938 1% /apps
```

System 2 - I have used this command ( df -k | tr -s " "  )

Output 2

```
$ df -k | tr -s " " 
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot
 2789856 384228 2263908 15% /
udev 99240232 600 99239632 1% /dev
tmpfs 99240232 32 99240200 1% /dev/shm
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1 1035660 81632 901420 9% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvhome
 690217 441040 213557 68% /home
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvopt
 3096336 2189872 749180 75% /opt
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvnetbk60
 4128448 1048232 2870504 27% /opt/openv
```

But I need the above output similar to Output 1 ( I mean in proper line like below )

Needed Output

```
$ df -k | tr -s " " 
Filesystem 1K-blocks Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvroot 2789856 384228 2263908 15% /
udev 99240232 600 99239632 1% /dev
tmpfs 99240232 32 99240200 1% /dev/shm
/dev/cciss/c0d0p1 1035660 81632 901420 9% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvhome 690217 441040 213557 68% /home
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvopt 3096336 2189872 749180 75% /opt
/dev/mapper/vg00-lvnetbk60 4128448 1048232 2870504 27% /opt/openv
```

Why I needed this , I need the output to be written in TXT document using the below code. It is properly working for the "System 1" but am not able to write for the "System 2" due to formatting issue.

Proper Code to Write the output to TXT file for System 1

```
unix_space=`df -k | tr -s " " | awk '{if (substr($4,1,(length($4)-1)) >=92) printf "%-30s\n",$1;}'|wc -l`

df -k | tr -s " " | awk 'BEGIN {print"##############################################################################\n      File System        Total Space       Free space  used%    Mounted Directory \n##############################################################################\n"} {if (substr($4,1,(length($4)-1)) >=92)  printf "%-30s|%-12s|%-12s|%-7s|%-30s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$7;}' > ${DATA}/logs/UNIXSPACE.txt
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. You piped the output to `tr`anslate but the result did not look like the second screenshot?

Comment: @sherrellbc they do appear to be `df` outputs from two different systems (the second one looks much like AIX). Siddharth, it helps other users of this site if you paste the text output instead of screenshots of text.

Comment: Please never post screenshots of text. Just copy/paste the text from your terminal directly into your question, and use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it look correct. That said, please [edit] your question and explain what you would like to see. Which of these images is your desired output? None of them?

Comment: I have fully modified the content for better understanding. Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: dont do all of that stuff on linuxes - that's crazy. just use `findmnt -Do%USED,OTHERFIELDS /the_mounts /you /want` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[use](http://linux.die.net/man/1/df) `df -P`:

> ```
>    -P, --portability
>           use the POSIX output format
> ```

```
$ df -P
Filesystem                    1024-blocks     Used Available Capacity Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_root       14987656  4220264   9999392      30% /
tmpfs                             4026908    60932   3965976       2% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1                          487652    36259    425793       8% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_tmp         5916420    47636   5561584       1% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg00-lv_var        20027260  1683820  17319440       9% /var
...
```